# Replace a set of characters in a string with an item from a list in python

Tags: python

I have a script I am trying to edit in python. In short, currently it ties together a bunch of files under certain counter balancing systems. I need to find and replace a certain keyword in all of them with an item in a list which has been randomised. This is the basic script without such functionality working fine below:

```
import random

# General comment: some of the script might be confusing because python
# uses zero-based numbering to index arrays

# read in the full list of scenario x conditions
f = open('scenarioList.xml', 'U')
data = f.read()
f.close()
inst = data.split("\n\n")

# read in the main portion of the data file (all before scenariolist)
f = open('interruptionstest1.xml', 'U')
MainScript = f.read()
f.close()

# read the final few lines at the end of the file
f = open('interruptionstest2.xml', 'U')
EndScript = f.read()
f.close()

# This specifies which scenarios are in which counterbalancing group
cGroups = [[0,3,6,9,12],
[1,4,7,10,13],
[2,5,8,11,14]]

conds = [inst[0:15],inst[15:30],inst[30:45]] # the xml strings divided up by condition

# this is the counterbalancing scheme (latin square)
cScheme = [[1,2,3],
[1,3,2],
[2 ,1 , 3],
[2 ,  3 ,  1],
[3 ,  1  , 2],
[3,   2 ,  1]]

# change the second index in the range to loop up to 60; set to 12 now for testing
for subj in range(1,61): 

    cRow = cScheme[(subj-1)%6] # use the modulus operator to find out which row to use in counterbalancing table

    scenArray = []

    # loop across scenario groups and look up their assigned interruption condition for this subj
    for group in range(0,3):
        #conds[cScheme[group]][i]

        scenArray.extend([ conds[cRow[group]-1][i] for i in cGroups[group]]) # use extend and not append here

    # randomize order of arrays---this is something you might modify to control this a bit more
    random.shuffle(scenArray)

    #insert workload and rest breaks with the exception of 8 which is a long rest
    testingArray = sum(([x,'\t\t\t<atc:instruction atc:idxref="Workload1"/>\n\t\t\t<atc:instruction atc:idxref="Anxiety1"/>\n\t\t\t<atc:instruction atc:idxref="Rest"/>'] if i != 7 else [x,'\t\t\t<atc:instruction atc:idxref="Workload1"/>\n\t\t\t<atc:instruction atc:idxref="Anxiety1"/>\n\t\t\t<atc:instruction atc:idxref="Restlong"/>'] for (i,x) in enumerate(scenArray)), [])

    f = open('ATC_Golf_Participant' + str(subj) + '.' + 'xml', 'w')
    f.write(MainScript + '\r\n\r\n'.join(testingArray) + '\n' + EndScript)
    f.close()
```

What I need: when the script loops`for subj in range(1,61):`, I need it to replace the word blunt1.VBS through to blunt5.VBS with an item at index [0-4]
of shuffled list `launch = ['launch1.VBS','launch2.VBS','launch3.VBS','launch4.VBS','launch5.VBS']`
 My solution thus far is failing miserably and I cannot work out quite why

```
    import random

# General comment: some of the script might be confusing because python
# uses zero-based numbering to index arrays

# read in the full list of scenario x conditions
f = open('scenarioList.xml', 'U')
data = f.read()
f.close()

#defines function shuffle
def Shuffle(x):
    b = x[:]#copies the launch commands
    random.shuffle(b)#shuffles the copy
    return b

#Specifies the ATC interruption launch commands
launch = ['launch1.VBS','launch2.VBS','launch3.VBS','launch4.VBS','launch5.VBS']

# read in the main portion of the data file (all before scenariolist)
f = open('interruptionstest1.xml', 'U')
MainScript = f.read()
f.close()

# read the final few lines at the end of the file
f = open('interruptionstest2.xml', 'U')
EndScript = f.read()
f.close()

# This specifies which scenarios are in which counterbalancing group
cGroups = [[0,3,6,9,12],
[1,4,7,10,13],
[2,5,8,11,14]]

# this is the counterbalancing scheme (latin square)
cScheme = [[1,2,3],
[1,3,2],
[2 ,1 , 3],
[2 ,  3 ,  1],
[3 ,  1  , 2],
[3,   2 ,  1]]

# change the second index in the range to loop up to 60; set to 12 now for testing
for subj in range(1,61):

    launchshuffled = [Shuffle(launch)]          
    datacopy = data.replace('blunt1.VBS',launchshuffled[0])
    datacopy = data.replace('blunt2.VBS',launchshuffled[1])
    datacopy = data.replace('blunt3.VBS',launchshuffled[2])
    datacopy = data.replace('blunt4.VBS',launchshuffled[3])
    datacopy = data.replace('blunt5.VBS',launchshuffled[4])

    inst = datacopy.split("\n\n") #split the data file
    conds = [inst[0:15],inst[15:30],inst[30:45]] # the xml strings divided up by condition

    cRow = cScheme[(subj-1)%6] # use the modulus operator to find out which row to use in counterbalancing table

    scenArray = []

    # loop across scenario groups and look up their assigned interruption condition for this subj
    for group in range(0,3):
        #conds[cScheme[group]][i]

        scenArray.extend([ conds[cRow[group]-1][i] for i in cGroups[group]]) # use extend and not append here

    # randomize order of arrays---this is something you might modify to control this a bit more
    random.shuffle(scenArray)

    #insert workload and rest breaks with the exception of 8 which is a long rest
    testingArray = sum(([x,'\t\t\t<atc:instruction atc:idxref="Workload1"/>\n\t\t\t<atc:instruction atc:idxref="Anxiety1"/>\n\t\t\t<atc:instruction atc:idxref="Rest"/>'] if i != 7 else [x,'\t\t\t<atc:instruction atc:idxref="Workload1"/>\n\t\t\t<atc:instruction atc:idxref="Anxiety1"/>\n\t\t\t<atc:instruction atc:idxref="Restlong"/>'] for (i,x) in enumerate(scenArray)), [])

    f = open('ATC_Golf_Participant' + str(subj) + '.' + 'xml', 'w')
    f.write(MainScript + '\r\n\r\n'.join(testingArray) + '\n' + EndScript)
    f.close()
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what errors it shows?

Comment: Error currently shown

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Backup\Test ATC August\ATCLab Condition Sorter Bullpup v1.6\generateScripts_1.6 TEST.py", line 48, in <module>
    str.datacopy = data.replace('blunt1.VBS',launchshuffled[0])
TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

Comment: you read `data` from a file than closed it before using it! put `f.close()` at the end.

Comment: I did use it by defining it as data right?

Comment: yes, my mistake. replace line `launchshuffled = [Shuffle(launch)]` with `launchshuffled = Shuffle(launch)      `

Comment: That got rid of the error thanks! But now the only BluntX.VBS that gets replaced is launchshuffed[0]

Comment: yes, see my answer, you should replace somelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many mistakes, `Shuffle(launch)` already a list , you dont need to add `[]`. You should also use `datacopy` for replacing since `string.replace` does not change strings in-place.

Replace:

```
launchshuffled = Shuffle(launch)          
datacopy = data.replace('blunt1.VBS',launchshuffled[0])
datacopy = datacopy.replace('blunt2.VBS',launchshuffled[1])
datacopy = datacopy.replace('blunt3.VBS',launchshuffled[2])
datacopy = datacopy.replace('blunt4.VBS',launchshuffled[3])
datacopy = datacopy.replace('blunt5.VBS',launchshuffled[4])
```

Comment: I'll bug test tomorrow then select \answer :)